# Multi project template references broken

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-web-api

I am building multi project template. One of the child projects is ASP.NET web application. When I export it as a single project template then everything is fine, but when included in multi project template, almost half of references are broken (Antlr3.Runtime, EntitiFramework, Microsoft.Owin and many others)

Multi project template looks like this:

```
<VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" Type="ProjectGroup" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005">
  <TemplateData>
    <Name>Web Api Solution Template</Name>
    <Description>Template commonly used in projects</Description>
    <ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>
    <ProjectSubType>
    </ProjectSubType>
    <SortOrder>1000</SortOrder>
    <CreateNewFolder>true</CreateNewFolder>
    <DefaultName>Web_API</DefaultName>
    <ProvideDefaultName>true</ProvideDefaultName>
    <LocationField>Enabled</LocationField>
    <EnableLocationBrowseButton>true</EnableLocationBrowseButton>
    <Icon>IconSolution.png</Icon>
  </TemplateData>
  <TemplateContent>
    <ProjectCollection>
      <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="Api">
        Api\MyTemplate.vstemplate
      </ProjectTemplateLink>
      <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="BLL">
        BLL\MyTemplate.vstemplate
      </ProjectTemplateLink>
      <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="DBModel">
        DBModel\MyTemplate.vstemplate
      </ProjectTemplateLink>
      <ProjectTemplateLink CopyParameters="true" ProjectName="Web">
        Web\MyTemplate.vstemplate
      </ProjectTemplateLink>
    </ProjectCollection>
  </TemplateContent>
</VSTemplate>
```

Why is it like that?

Comment: Having the exact same issue with VS 2015. Did you ever find a solution to the issue? I am thinking it has something to do with the packages.config files in each project template

Comment: @MichaelTranchida see answer below

Comment: usually your hintpaths are broken I found altering the hint paths to an extra level up solved the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it by using template wizard extension. Basically what I did, was remove all the preinstalled nuget packages from child projects and add them with wizard extension so that the end of project.vstemplate looks like this: (api in this case)

```
    <WizardExtension>
    <Assembly>NuGet.VisualStudio.Interop, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a</Assembly>
    <FullClassName>NuGet.VisualStudio.TemplateWizard</FullClassName>
  </WizardExtension>
  <WizardData>
    <packages>
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Cors" version="5.2.3" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage" version="5.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin" version="5.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="5.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Owin" version="1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Cors" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.MicrosoftAccount" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twitter" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.3" targetFramework="net45" />
    </packages>
</WizardData>
</VSTemplate>
```

As far as I remember, you can copy paste the Assembly part as it won't change in the future.

Comment: Thank you, looks like what I'm going to need. I am looking at Sidewaffle right now as it looks promising with regard to making changes to the template and having everything update automatically. Might want to watch [this video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Visual-Studio-Toolbox/SideWaffle) on Channel 9 / Visual Studio Toolbox.

Comment: This almost solved my problem but in order to fix my problem needed to add the property `repository="template"` to the tag `<packages>` and add all required `.nupkg` files into the root folder of the project.

Comment: I've just run into this issue. @JoëlSalamin When you say "Root folder" of the project. Is that all the "roots"? I have multiple proj's in one sln. Keen to get this to work.

Comment: @TezWingfield I also have multiple projects in one solution, you need to add the property `repository="template"` to the tag `<packages>` in every projects that requires NuGet packages.

Comment: @JoëlSalamin Thank you for the clarification, really appreciate that!

Answer (score 0):

Use [Sidewaffle](https://github.com/ligershark/side-waffle/wiki/How-to-create-a-multi-project-template). When you modify your project(s), no need to update .vstemplates, nugets, any of that. Just rebuild the .vsix project (release), and double click the .vsix in the release folder